# Nested Find in 2D Nesting Lists

Tags: python

I have a Nested 2D list:

```
nested =[[4, 6, 8],
         [3, 5, 3]]

found = None
for row in nested:
    for value in row:
        if value > 5:
            found = value
print(found)
```

Terminal output:

```
8
```

However, I was expecting to see this as my terminal output:

```
6, 8
```

And my logic is obviously because 6 is also greater than 5 in the list of integers in both of the rows in the list. Why did it only print 8?

I tried to index the row in my for loop statements and it got me nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`found` can only ever hold a single integer value in your code. Instead, you could make it a list of values that is appended to, or `print` each matching number inside the `if` statement.

```py
found = []
for row in nested:
    for value in row:
        if value > 5:
            found.append(value)
print(found)
```

This can be written more simply with a list comprehension.

```py
found = [value for row in nested for value in row if value > 5]
print(found)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to print the found elements and you don;t need to keep them, your code is amost correct, but you need to put the print inside the nested loops

```
nested =[[4, 6, 8],
         [3, 5, 3]]

found = None   # you don't actually need this line
for row in nested:
    for value in row:
        if value > 5:
            found = value   # you could directly do print(value)
            print(found)    # since you are not keeping the elements.
```

If you need to keep the elements, consider appending them in a list, which you can print at the end

```
nested =[[4, 6, 8],
         [3, 5, 3]]

foundElements = []
for row in nested:
    for value in row:
        if value > 5:
            foundElements.append(value)
print(foundElements)
```

Comment: You made it easy. Ty

Answer (score 1):

The reason of print only 8 is because you put print statement outside the loop. so that's why it only prints the last element. If you want to print all the values that are greater than 5 you can enhance your code like below:

```
nested =[[4, 6, 8],
     [3, 5, 3]]

found = []
for row in nested:
    for value in row:
        if value > 5:
            found.append(value)
print(found)
```